# sort particular rows using mysql order case

Tags: mysql, sorting, case, rows, using

I have a table with incremented id from 1,2,3...and so on. What i want is just to sort the data in descending order on the basis of field 'id' except first two rows. I tried using below query:-

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY CASE WHEN id<3 THEN 0 ELSE id END DESC
```

It give me the result like

```
id    name
5     Meal
4     Apparel
3     Electronics
1     Sports
2     Lifestyle
```

But output should come like

```
id    name
1     Sports
2     Lifestyle
5     Meal
4     Apparel
3     Electronics
```

Is there any way to achieve this by using such query?

Comment: it may be slightly more advantageuos to add an order/weight column and then you can just use that to order your records

Comment: No, i can not add any other column to give order or weight. I need to get it at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id < 3 THEN 10000 - id ELSE id END DESC;
-- ----------------------------^
-- use a very large number
```

## Edit:

A better solution which does not require hard coding `10000`:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id < 3 THEN id ELSE 3 END, id DESC
-- ---------------------^              ^
-- ------------------------------------|
-- these numbers must be same
```

Comment: How about this ?  SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 0  WHEN id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, id DESC;

Comment: I got above query working in any case whether there are million of rows. The idea is that we need to assign temporary number to particular id that are not required to be sorted... So eventually if there are first 5 rows need not to be sorted then query would be like SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 0  WHEN id = 2 THEN 1 WHEN id = 3 THEN 2  WHEN id = 4 THEN 3 WHEN id = 5 THEN 4  WHEN id = 6 THEN 5 ELSE 999 END, id DESC;

Comment: Much better solution than previous :)

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
CASE WHEN id<3 THEN id ELSE ~id END
```

And instead of case, use `IF`:

```
IF(id<3, id, ~id)
```

Comment: @neeraj Sorry, had a typo. Meant to do `~` instead of `-`.

Comment: This is much better solution and in this case we will not need to bother about number of rows of table. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're ordering by descending ids, so the order is 5-4-3-0-0. You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY CASE WHEN id<3 THEN 9999 ELSE id END DESC
```

But that is not a perfect solution

Comment: The first option is working. But Why do you think that it is not a perfect solution? BTW i dont like to use union

Comment: Oh i see it does not work for large data. Means if i change the condition from <3 to <10 in a large table.

Comment: If there are two or more `9999` in your result, MySQL is free to sort these rows any way it likes. Change it to `CASE WHEN id < 3 THEN 10000 - id ELSE id END` just to be sure.